# Division with numerator 2^64

Tags: math, division, integer-division, integer-arithmetic

How to to divide the constant 2^64 (i.e. `ULLONG_MAX` + 1) by `uint64` larger than 2, without using `unit128`?

In other words, given `x` such as  `2 <= x <= 2^64-1`, how to obtain the quotient `2^64 / x`, using just `uint64`?

The problem is that I cannot represent 2^64, let alone to divide it so I was hoping there is a trick which would simulate the result.

Comment: Given your constants, may I assume that you are limiting this question to the C#, C++, F#, and Visual Basic languages? This is trivial in many other languages, such as in Python.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Basically any language without `int128_t` or bignums, yes.

Comment: Perhaps just do `(2^63)/x` and then multiply that result by `2`?

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 then the result is necessarily even, but that's not right in general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take `ULLONG_MAX / denom`, and add 1 if `denom` is a power of 2. In pseudocode:

```
if (denom == 0) {
    throw ZeroDivisionException;
} else if (denom == 1) {
    throw OverflowException;
} else {
    return ULLONG_MAX / denom + (denom & (denom-1) == 0);
}
```

Alternatively, take `ULLONG_MAX / denom` for odd `denom`, and take `2^63 / (denom / 2)` for even `denom`:

```
if (denom == 0) {
    throw ZeroDivisionException;
} else if (denom == 1) {
    throw OverflowException;
} else if (denom & 1) {
    return ULLONG_MAX / denom;
} else {
    return (1ULL << 63) / (denom >> 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> How to to divide the constant 2^64 (i.e. ULLONG_MAX + 1) by uint64 larger than 2

a/b --> (a-b)/b + 1

First subtract `x` from (max _value + 1), then divide by `x`, add 1.

```
// C solution:
uint64_t foo(uint64_t x) {
  return (0u - x)/x + 1; // max_value + 1 is 0 and unsigned subtraction wraps around.
}
```

Of course division by 0 is a no-no.  Code works for `x >= 2`, but not `x == 1` as the quotient is also not representable.